# teensyduino with teensy LC: cannot include multiple files in sketch

Tags: teensy

I'm trying to get a rather large sketch working with a teensy LC.  I'd like to break it into headers and C files, but the multi-file sketch fails to compile.  When I put everything into a single, monolithic sketch, it runs fine.  I've #included the h files where they are needed, using single quotes, and have confirmed that my h files are in the same folder as my sketch.  Is there an additional step to go through specific to teensy?  I've managed to do this tons of times using a standard arduino.

Here is a basic sketch:

This is the main sketch file:

```
   #include "tst.h"
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  doNothing();
}
```

This is tst.h

```
void doNothing();
```

This is tst.c

```
#include "tst.h"
void doNothing()
{
  int i = 0;
}
```

I get the  error "undefined reference to doNothing() in function loop"

Comment: Could you provide source code and compilation errors ? I have created a small test with Arduino 1.6.13 + Teensyduino 1.33 with a mylib.cpp/mylib.h in the same folder as .INO file and after selecting "Teensy LC" device no problem detected to compile and link.

Comment: My source code is quite long.  I am using C, not c++.  Would that matter?  If I have time soon I'll make a trial sketch with just a few small functions to test and upload.

Comment: No problem, take your time to create a minimal source code. When you say **"I am using C, not c++"**, did you  use a `".c"` file instead of `".cpp"` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I have three files, the main sketch, one *.h file, and one *.c file

Comment: I've edited the post to include a minimal sketch. I wonder, is the a build order setting I'm missing?

Comment: So, the first and easiest solution is to rename your `"test.c"` file to `"test.cpp"`. This is the default extension expected by the C++ compiler used by Arduino IDE.

Comment: Are all the *.c files opened (show up in the tabs near the top of the window) in the Arduino SDK when you compile?

Comment: Even if the `"test.c"` and the `"test.h"` appear on the top, the `"test.c"` seems to be compiled `"mylib.c.o"` and the `doNothing` is present inside. But the  error is always `UsingCpp.ino:14: undefined reference to 'doNothing()'`.

Comment: Yes, they are all part of the sketch and are tabs at the top. @J.Piquard: do you see the same errors?

Comment: I duplicated your error (guessing you called the 1st file "tst.ino") using Arduino 1.8.0.  @J.Piquard suggestion appears correct, you need to use the *.cpp extension.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it handily.  I wonder why, though? I was under the impression that Arduino used C, with a bunch of cpp functionality added in through emulation of some sort.  I guess I'm wrong, obviously :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the error "undefined reference to doNothing() in function loop"

The C++ compiler cannot find doNothing(). This is mainly due to the incomplete header file and mix of C and C++.

Two things are needed to avoid this type of problem; 1) protect the file from multiple includes (in the same compile), 2) make the function visible to the C++ compiler as a C function (without name mangling).

tst.h:

```
#ifndef TST_H
#define TST_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

void doNothing();

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
#endif
```

Cheers!

Comment: I admit I'm still learning c++, but why is my function not c++?

Comment: The build rules for files with the extension .c will use the c-compiler (gcc). If you rename the file and use the extension .cpp the build rules will use the c++-compiler.

Comment: Oh, yes I see.  So the function itself was not strictly c, but the fact that it was in A C file was the problem?

Comment: Correct! If you had used overloading, reference parameters, classes, etc (i.e. a language difference) then the C-compiler would have flagged an error. Now actually the linker flags the error as the C function does not have the same compiled name (aka manged name) as the C++ function.